# Change primary button style on UWP Xamarin dialog box

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, mobile, uwp

I'm setting up a Xamarin project that will have an Android and Windows version. I'm using Acr UserDialogs NuGet package for my dialog boxes. Our business users would like a prompt with no "Default looking" button. I was wondering if there is an easy way to change the style on the primary button to make it look just the same as the other one.

The method being used is `UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync`

In my screenshot below I just want both buttons to have the same coloring.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change primary button style on UWP Xamarin dialog box

Please check this [link](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Acr.UserDialogs/Platforms/Uwp/UserDialogsImpl.cs#L93), it was implement with [`MessageDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) control within UWP platform, derive from rob's [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc4e477f-27b2-48b6-9210-a2b7db31a67c/how-to-change-color-of-message-dialog-button?forum=winappswithhtml5), we could not custom `MessageDialog`

> No. The MessageDialog is not customizable. Its button will always show the app's theme color as set in its manifest.

If we do want to edit the color, we need to change in manifest file which will set it default color for **whole** application.